# jQuery Live Search: Specifying searchable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, livesearch

I'm having some trouble with the [jQuery Live Search plugin](https://github.com/nakajima/jquery-livesearch), specifying which elements should be searchable. I've created a couple jsFiddles to demonstrate the issue.

**Note:** The default usage of jQuery Live Search simply filters a list of words ([demo](http://nakajima.github.com/jquery-livesearch/)). My desired usage however filters from blocks of content within the list items:

```
<li>
    <h2>Australia</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<li>
```

**So what's the problem?**

Targeting the `<li>` as the searchable element works fine - all content within it becomes searchable in the live search results.

However targeting the `<h2>` (the only part I want searchable) causes the results list to break (all are hidden) despite the counter showing the correct result.

**How do I reproduce?**

Check out [this working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/pcfLJ/) with the plugin targetting the `<li>` as the searchable area. As you'll see, searching a country (case sensitive) works correctly (the `<h2>`) as well as searching "Lorem" returning all 4 results (`<p>` is also searchable).

What I want to do is make only the `<h2>` searchable, not anything else within the `<li>`. [Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/pcfLJ/4/) with that set. Now when searching a country, the correct result number is displayed but the `<li>` of that result remains hidden incorrectly. A search for "Lorem" correctly returns no results and a result number of 0.

It seems when an element within the `<li>` is targeted it breaks the show/hide of the `<li>` itself. Is this a bug with the plugin or something I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this callback:

```
on.results(function(results) {
    $('.no-filter-results').hide();
    $('.filter-results li').hide();
    results.show();
});
```

The `results` parameter contains a reference to the elements you're targeting (in this case the `h2` elements).

You're setting all `li` elements to be hidden first in this line:

```
$('.filter-results li').hide();
```

And then afterwards setting just the `h2` elements to be visible with this line:

```
results.show();
```

Obviously this is not working because the parent `li` is still hidden.

The solution is to show the parent `li` of the `h2` in the result, like so:

```
results.parent('li').show();
```

This explains why it was working when you were targeting the `li` element previously.